# Accessing variables from my __init__ function, from another function

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

So I have my main function called **init** that holds my main tkinter window. I have another function that is called login_db that is trying to access the entry boxes of the **init**.

```py
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
        mb_username = tkinter.Entry()
        mb_password = tkinter.Entry()
        mb_login = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=self.login_db(mb_username.get(),mb_password.get()))
    def login_db(self,username,password):
        print("Received")
        print(username)
        print(password)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store them in the object using references to `self`.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
    self.mb_username = tkinter.Entry()
    self.mb_password = tkinter.Entry()
    self.mb_login = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=self.login_db(mb_username.get(),mb_password.get()))
```

Comment: Just wanted to add too that in the login command had to passed as                  self.mb_login = tkinter.Button(text="Login", command=self.login_db)  and then called the .get() of the entry boxes in login_db.